# rails-jquery-autocomplete: list populated from instance is blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, autocomplete, mongoid

I am trying to setup rails-jquery-autocomplete gem and I have the jquery-ui-rails gem installed. I have a "transactions" model that has names and I want to access that list of names as the autocomplete items in a form for a different model called "bills". According to the documentation I added the autocomplete line to the controller but when I go to the link the list is blank. I think the issue is because I want to call an instance but I am unsure. Is there something I am missing to access this list. When I go to the list link it shows an empty array.

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
//= require autocomplete-rails
```

application.css

```
 *= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
```

bill_form_view

```
  <%= f.fields_for :bill do |b| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
      <% if @user.bill.cell_phone.blank?  %>
          <%= b.label :cell_phone, "Cell Phone Company Name"%><br />
          <%= b.text_field :cell_phone, autocomplete: autocomplete_bills_path %>
      <% end %>
```

transaction model

```
class Transaction
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :user

  field :trans_names,     type: Array
end
```

transaction controller

```
class Tenants::TransactionsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    autocomplete :transaction, :trans_names, limit: 5, full: true
  ...
end
```

bill model

```
class Bill
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :user

  field :cell_phone
end
```

routes

```
    resource  :transactions do
      collection do
        get 'autocomplete_transaction_trans_names'
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed my issue which was due to the view. In the form I had

```
<%= b.text_field :cell_phone, autocomplete: autocomplete_bills_path %>
```

I could not see the autocomplete list but when I changed it to

```
<%= b.autocomplete_field :cell_phone, autocomplete: autocomplete_bills_path %>
```

The autocomplete began to work. So problem solved.